# Passing value to pop up window from link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a jsp page with table. I have two links in the table, for editing and deleting. When I click the delete link, a pop up window appears, from and when i confirm delete i need the page to divert to its action class. Here are the parts of the code.
jsp page:

```
<%-- 
Document   : newjsp1
Created on : 4 Dec, 2015, 9:49:07 AM
Author     : najee
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <%-- other codes here  --%>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Employee ID </th>
                <th> First Name </th>
                <th> Second Name </th>
                <th> Date of Birth </th>
                <th> Emirates Id </th>
                <th> Type Of Employee </th>
                <th style="width: 3.5em;"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <s:iterator value="empco">

            <tr>

                <td><s:property value="e_id"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="fname"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="sname"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="birthdate"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="emiratesid"/></td>
            <td><s:property value="typeofemployee"/></td>
            <td>
            <s:url var="IdValue" action="EditStaffDetails"><s:param name="IdValue"><s:property value="e_id"/></s:param></s:url><a href="${IdValue}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
            <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" ></i></a> <%-- delete link --%>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator> 
    </table>
    <%-- other codes here  --%>

    <div class="modal small fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p class="error-text"><i class="fa fa-warning modal-icon"></i>Are you sure you want to delete the user?<br>This cannot be undone.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                    <form action="deleteEmployee" method="post">    
                        <input type="hidden" name="employeeId" value="<s:property value="e_id"/>" />
                               <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="Submit" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 <%-- other codes here  --%>

</body>
```

I want to pass the value from the corresponding column Employee Id to the input box employeeId in the popup window when I click the delete link in a row.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: which library you are using for showing modal popup? Is it a bootstrap or something else?

Comment: try alertify js for confirmation of delete.

Comment: @vijayP - yes, its bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a attribute `data-id` in the link that triggers the modal with the id value ,bind a click event to that link and pass the data to the modal hidden input

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Employee ID </th>
            <th> First Name </th>
            <th> Second Name </th>
            <th> Date of Birth </th>
            <th> Emirates Id </th>
            <th> Type Of Employee </th>
            <th style="width: 3.5em;"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <s:iterator value="empco">

        <tr>

            <td><s:property value="e_id"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="fname"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="sname"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="birthdate"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="emiratesid"/></td>
        <td><s:property value="typeofemployee"/></td>
        <td>
        <s:url var="IdValue" action="EditStaffDetails"><s:param name="IdValue"><s:property value="e_id"/></s:param></s:url><a href="${IdValue}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        <a href="#myModal" data-id="${IdValue}" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" ></i></a> <%-- delete link --%>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator> 
</table>
<%-- other codes here  --%>

<div class="modal small fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="error-text"><i class="fa fa-warning modal-icon"></i>Are you sure you want to delete the user?<br>This cannot be undone.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                <form action="deleteEmployee" method="post">    
                    <input type="hidden" name="employeeId" value="null" />

                           <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('a[href="#myModal"]').on('click',function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $('input[name="employeeId"]').val(id);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ttdswa2e/

or:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal',function(e){
       var id = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
      $('input[name="employeeId"]').val(id);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z9eqxhey/